# How to keep data when run command calabash-android run

Tags: android, calabash

My Android application have to synchronize data in the first time. It spend about 15 minute for synchronization. And in secondtime, I don't need get data from server. But when a run calabash to test feature:
calabash-android run MyApp.apk
I feel it remove all data in my app and rebuild application.
So, how to keep data when I run feature Scenario for my app?

My scenario :

```
   Feature: create work order
```

As a techinical
  I want to create work orders
  So I can manage WO easier

Scenario: Technician create work order successfully

```
 Given I am on the Create Work Order Screen
    And I select customer name which is "Harris Teeter"
    And I select equipment serial number which is "1A100438"
    And I select Job code "1" and then is "100 HOUR SERVICE"
    And I select order type "401"
    And I input valid title "Create new work order"
    And I input valid description "Work order description"
    Then I see the successful messages "The new work order has been created successfully"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try command

```
NO_LAUNCH=1 cucumber --format html --out index.html features/Your_feature_file.feature
```

It won't relaunch your app. But you need to run the app first time before you run this command. As long as your app in the foreground this command works.

Note: I use this for iPhone testing it should work on android too.

Comment: This is not working in calabash-android. Do we have any alternative for this in calabash-android?

Answer (score 0):

This is because calabash-android reinstall app before run every scenario.
To avoid that, you can comment this code in app_installation_hooks.rb file in android support folder

```
uninstall_apps
install_app(ENV["TEST_APP_PATH"])
install_app(ENV["APP_PATH"])
```

Comment: you only need to comment `uninstall_apps`. The other 2 lines keep them as they are.